# How to remove Company and Fax field from onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, onepage-checkout, rwd, customer-address

I'm would like to remove company & fax field from the checkout page, i already comment out the company and fax field, but it doesn't work.

I removed it from:

1. `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`
2. `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

And also from RWD template.

Comment: Do you use any extension for your checkout page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you will also have to comment the code in the following files if you're on the RWD theme:

- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

Comment: Yes, i already comment out the code, but still doesn't work

Comment: @firewalls double check the path of the template by enabling the template path hints: http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: Danggg! It's working :D